# Stuck on Animation with a Callback method

Tags: jquery

I'm currently studying JQuery.  I need to make the old image fade out and the new image fade in when a new image is selected.  I have the code that selects the image but now I need to put that in a call back method that fades out the current image and fades in the new image.  The fade duration is 1 second. I'm stuck trying to accomplish this.  Any help would be appreciated.  The code I have so far is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // preload images
  $("#image_list a").each(function() {
    var swappedImage = new Image();
    swappedImage.src = $(this).attr("href");
  });

  // set up event handlers for links 
  $("#image_list a").click(function(evt) {
    var caption = $(this).attr("title");
    var imageURL = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#caption").text(caption);
    $("#image").attr("src", imageURL);
    // cancel the default action of the link
    evt.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Image Swap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="image_swap1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <h1>Ram Tap Combined Test</h1>
    <ul id="image_list">
      <li>
        <a href="images/h1.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-1">
          <img src="thumbnails/t1.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/h2.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-2">
          <img src="thumbnails/t2.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/h3.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-3">
          <img src="thumbnails/t3.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/h4.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-4">
          <img src="thumbnails/t4.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/h5.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-5">
          <img src="thumbnails/t5.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/h6.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-6">
          <img src="thumbnails/t6.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h2 id="caption">James Allison: 1-1</h2> 
    <p>
      <img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="" id="image">
    </p>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _"need to make the old image fade out and the new image fade in when a new image is selected"_ `.fadeOut()` , `.fadeIn()` not appear at `js`  ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

1) Make the image fade out.

2) Then after certain delay, make it fade in with the new values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#image_list a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#image').fadeOut(500);
    change($(this)).delay(500);
  });
});

var change = function(img) {
  var caption = img.attr("title");
  var imageURL = img.attr("href");
  $("#caption").text(caption);
  $("#image").attr("src", imageURL);
  $("#image").fadeIn();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h1>Ram Tap Combined Test</h1>

  <ul id="image_list">
    <li>
      <a href="images/h1.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-1">
        <img src="thumbnails/t1.jpg" alt="" />
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/h2.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-2">
        <img src="thumbnails/t2.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/h3.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-3">
        <img src="thumbnails/t3.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/h4.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-4">
        <img src="thumbnails/t4.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/h5.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-5">
        <img src="thumbnails/t5.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/h6.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-6">
        <img src="thumbnails/t6.jpg" alt="">
      </a>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <h2 id="caption">James Allison: 1-1</h2> 
  <p>
    <img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="" id="image">
  </p>
</section>
```